# How Can I create and push repo from local to gitub

Tags: git, github

I was wondering if there is a way to create repo in GitHub from local cmd and push the repo to the remote.

Like I do:

```
git branch IAmLocal
git push -u branch IAmLocal
```

It will through error as not existing repo in the remote (which is expected), as a learning I am putting this question to find a way (*if there is and I not aware of it*) if we could put this repo in GitHub without creating repo in GitHub manually.

**Update**

After seeing duplicate tag I would like to confirm that I am looking for a way where I can create remote repo and push it from local using CMD.

Happy learning!

Comment: There is an [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create) to create repositories. Whether someone has wrapped this in a CLI tool is another question.

Comment: Your creating the bare new repo, in that case git branch IAmLocal won't work. Create the origin/master and then  create your branch and then you can push the branch to the origin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+create+repository+command+line

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create an account on git-hub and repo

Go to the project folder and run

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'You commint message';
git push
```

Comment: `git push` needs a configured default remote, which won't be there from a straight `git init`; something like `git remote add <name> <uri>` would have to come first, which assumes the repo at the other end already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do so:

1. Create a git account
2. Creating a repository
3. Go to the project folder and run

   git clone https://github.com/USER/demo.git

USER = your user name
demo.git - yout repo name

Then copy u files in this folder where u clone and run:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'You commint message';
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a repository on GitHub using the GitHub command line API as follows:

```
curl -u 'USER' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"REPO"}'
```

*Note: you need `curl` installed on your OS.*

Another option - install [this](https://github.com/github/hub) utility, then you can run many GitHub commands on your cmd. to create a new repo run this command:

```
$ hub create shaykia/test
```